# Binomial Distribution - combinations formula

Tags: binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem, binomial-distribution

The binomial formula goes as follows: $$ Pr(X = k) = {n\choose k}  p^k (1-p)^{n-k}$$

I understand why they multiply by $p^k$ and $(1-p)^{n-k}$, but why do they use the combinations formula and not the permutations one?

Comment: Imagine that you have $n$ events, and you want to know the chances that exactly $k$ of these events succeed : $~n \in \Bbb{Z^+}, k \in \{1,2,\cdots, n\}.$  One way this could happen is if events $\{1,2,\cdots,k\}$ succeeded, and events $\{k+1, \cdots, n\}$ failed.  This specific possibility generates the factor $p^k~(1-p)^{(n-k)}.$  However, how many ways are there of determining which of the $k$ events (out of the $n$ total events) succeeded?  ...see next comment

Comment: Instead of it being the specific situation where events $\{1,2,\cdots,k\}$ succeeded, it could have been **any** $k$ events selected from $\{1,2,\cdots, n\}.$  So, you have to apply the factor that represents choosing $k$ elements (without replacement) from $\{1,2,\cdots, n\}.$  The number of ways of choosing $k$ elements, without replacement from $\{1,2,\cdots,n\}$ is $\binom{n}{k}.$

Comment: As a specific example, suppose that $n = 4$ and $k = 2$.  Then, the number of ways of choosing $2$ events out of $4$ is represented by the choices $\{1,2\}, \{1,3\}, \{1.4\}, \{2,3\}, \{2.4\}, \{3,4\}.$  Here, you don't distinguish between (for example) the set $\{1,3\}$ and the set $\{3,1\}.$  They both represent that events $(1)$ and $(3)$ succeeded, and events $(2)$ and $(4)$ failed.

Comment: With $n\choose{k}$ instead of $P(n,k)$ you are not specifying the order in which you wish to pick the k elements. It's not that event A succeeded first and then event B succeeded. If they both do, then they both do. Hence there is no order associated with it

Comment: @user2661923 I get your point, where {1,3} and {3,1} are the same but could you explain it through a real example like coin flipping so I can see it in action

Comment: If you flip a coin $4$ times, what are the chances of exactly $2$ heads?  Here, $p = (1/2) = (1 - p)$, so the chances of coin flips $(1)$ and $(2)$ coming up heads, while coin flips $(3)$ and $(4)$ come up tails is $p^2(1 - p)^2 = (1/2)^2(1/2)^2 = (1/2)^4$.  Further, there are $6$ ways of selecting the two events out of four to come up heads.  These $6$ ways are specifically enumerated in my last comment.  Therefore, the chance of exactly $2$ heads is $$6 \times (1/2)^4 = \binom{4}{2} (1/2)^2(1/2)^2.$$  This analogizes to $$\binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{(n-k)}.$$

Comment: By the way, consider what happens if you flip a coin $4$ times, and you consider the chance of exactly $k$ heads, where $k \in \{0,1,2,3,4\}.$  Since these are the only possible values for $k$, the sum of all $5$ of these possibilities must equal $1$.  This implies that $$\sum_{k=0}^{4} \left[\binom{4}{k}(1/2)^k(1/2)^{(4-k)}\right] ~\text{must} ~= 1.$$  Sure enough, $$[(1 \times (1/2)^4)] + [(4 \times (1/2)^4)] + [(6 \times (1/2)^4)] + [(4 \times (1/2)^4)] + [(1 \times (1/2)^4)] = 1.$$  See also [Pascal's Triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_triangle).

Comment: @user2661923 Thanks for the explanation!